# should devname be unique for shared Interrupt using devm_request_threaded_irq

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver

In Linux Kernel, "devm_request_threaded_irq"[1] is used to register IRQ handler, and when irqflags used is "IRQF_SHARED " (sharing interrupt among multiple devices), is it necessary to have unique "devname" (the second last argument to "devm_request_threaded_irq" ) for each of the device that register the handler?

[1] https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/interrupt.h#L205

Comment: No, it does not need to be unique, although unique names look more professional in /proc/interrupts. Note that the `devname` pointer passed to the request gets stored in the `struct irqaction` created by the function, so whatever string `devname` points to needs to remain valid in memory until the IRQ is freed. Since you are using devres-managed resources, you could use `devm_kasprintf()` to construct a unique name for your device/interrupt.

Comment: @IanAbbott, do you see any conflicts or un-defined behavior when same name is used for multiple devices sharing the IRQ pointed by devname or devname is just used for some debugging purpose ?

Comment: It is there mostly for informational purposes. It is quite common for drivers to use a fixed string (especially in older code). The string is used in /proc/interrupts and also in the names of subdirectories under /proc/irq/$IRQNUMBER/. (I have no idea what those subdirectories are for. They seem to be empty.)

Comment: @IanAbbott new IRQ stuff goes to _/sys/kernel/irq/$IRQNUMBER_ (and to be precise this has to be _$vIRQNUMBER_, note **v** there for virtual, a.k.a. Linux IRQ).

Comment: Yes, "/sys/kernel/irq/$IRQNUMBER/actions" also uses the `devname` strings in a comma-separated list of sharers similar to that in "/proc/interrupts" but with no space after the comma. Thanks @0andriy.